# Loop through rows with prepared select statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need loop through all rows with prepared statement. Cant realize it. It always shows last row in table.

I already tried:

```
$stmtprocessors = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='processors'");
$stmtprocessors->execute();
$stmtprocessors->bind_result($id,$name,$description_short,$description_long,$price,$price_vat,$stock,$deleted,$parameters,$purchases,$discount,$category,$reference,$date);

if ($stmtprocessors->num_rows > 0)
{               
    while ($stmtprocessors->fetch()) {
        echo $id;
    }
}
```

I tryed to print_r($stmtprocessors) and this is result:

```
mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => -1 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 0 [field_count] => 14 [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 1 )
```

Comment: why not just fetch and echo $row['id']?

Comment: it will show last row .. it's the last iteration..

Comment: @treyBake how you mean fetch and echo row?

Comment: Before the loop, what is `echo $stmtprocessors->num_rows;`?

Comment: @Qirel i edited my question and now it doesnt show anything

Comment: Not sure how you are getting that one id. `[num_rows] => 0` sounds like no rows are being matched. Did this work prior to using prepared statements?

Comment: You're probably dmping a different statement - `affected_rows` is 1, and that can't happen for a select query.

Comment: @Jacob I ment that you should *print* it, so we can see what value it has.

Comment: @Qirel it shows 0

Comment: but select query is matching with my mysql database (when i run it in sql in phpmyadmin it shows me results

Comment: @Qirel `affected_rows` is `-1`, that's to be expected.

Comment: @Barmar *whoops*, missed the dash in front. Nevermind me then. :D